# Wildcard filter in aws-nuke

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, wildcard, aws-nuke

I am using aws-nuke to cleanup an AWS account, but some resources tagged for keeping I'd like to keep. Is there way in the filter to specify all resource types with a specific property set, e.g. something like

```
presets:
  keep:
    filters:
       *:
         - property: "tag:do-not-nuke"
         - value: "true"
```

or the only way to do this is list all resource types individually?